# Can (Open Studio) Talend be used to automate a data load from a folder to vertica?

Tags: database-schema, etl, talend, vertica

I have been looking at a way to automate my data loads into vertica instead of manually exporting flat files each time, and stumbled upon the ETL Talend.

I have been working with a test folder containing multiple csv files, and am attempting to find a way to build a job so the file can be put into vertica.

However, I see in the open studio version (free), if your files do not have the same schema, this becomes next to impossible without having the dynamic schema option which is in the enterprise version.

I start with tFileList and attempt to iterate through tFileInputDelimited, but the schemas are not uniform, so of course it will stop the processing.

So, long story short, am I correct in assuming that there is no way to automate data loads in the free version of Talend if you have a folder consisting of files with different schemas?

If anyone has any suggestions for other open source ETLs to look at or a solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the **CURRENT_FILE** variable from a tFileList compenent and then send a file down different route depening on the file name. You'd then create a tFileInputDelimited for each file. For example if you had two files named file1.csv and file2.csv, right click the tFileList and choose **Trigger>Run If**. In the run if condition type **((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")).toLowerCase().matches("file1.csv")** and drag it to the tFileInputDelimited set up to handle file1.csv. Do the same for file2.csv, changing the filename in the run if condition.